# How to convert mysql join query using criteria in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I want to convert the below MySql query to hibernate using criteria.
tbl_state and tbl_country are the tables that I want to join where tbl_state and tbl_country has a common field country_id.

```
    select s.*,c.country_name from tbl_state s,tbl_country c where 
    s.country_id=c.country_id ORDER BY s.state_name 
    + order + " LIMIT " + pagesize + " OFFSET " + pagesize * pagenum;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you should create entity for tables.
we assume that State is entity for tbl_state and Country is entity for tbl_country.

Country Entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_country")
public class Country {
  private Integer countryId;

   @Id
   @Column(name="country_id")
   public String getCountryId(){
      return countryId;
   }  
}
```

State Entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_state")
public class State {

  private Integer stateId;
  private String stateName;
  private Country country;

   @Id
   @Column(name="state_id")
   public String getStateId(){
      return stateId;
   }  

  @Column(name="state_name")
  public String getStateName(){
      return stateName;
  }  

  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="country_id")
  public Country getCountry(){
     return country;
 }
```

}

Criteria code:

```
Criteria stateCriteria = session.createCriteria(State.class);
Criteria countryCriteria = stateCriteria.createCriteria("country");
stateCriteria.addOrder(Order.desc("stateName"));
stateCriteria.setFirstResult(pagesize * pagenum);
stateCriteria.setMaxResults(pagesize);
List results = stateCriteria.list();
```

for custom result, you should create a dto class.for example StateDto :

```
 public class StateDto {

   private String stateName;
   private String countryName;

   public String getStateName() {
       return stateName;
   }

   public void setStateName(String stateName) {
       this.stateName = stateName;
   }

   public String getCountryName() {
       return countryName;
   }

   public void setCountryName(String countryName) {
      this.countryName = countryName;
  }
```

}

Then your criteria code can be like below code.

```
Criteria stateCriteria = session.createCriteria(State.class);
Criteria countryCriteria = stateCriteria.createCriteria("country");
stateCriteria.addOrder(Order.desc("stateName"));
stateCriteria.setFirstResult(pagesize * pagenum);
stateCriteria.setMaxResults(pagesize);
stateCriteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
            .add(Projections.property("stateName").as("stateName"))
            .add(Projections.property("country.name").as("countryName")));
List<StateDto> results = stateCriteria.list();
```

Comment: Are you have country name in Country Entity? you can have access to country through state. I mean with state.getCountry().getName().

Comment: Yes ..How to add this to criteria